# PySide， how to setup QMessageBox text format?

Tags: python, pyside

I want to setup QMessageBox text format, but I can't find a valid method.

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.information(
    self, 
    "Confirm delete!", 
    "Are you sure you want to delete file?\n %s" % filename,
    QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No,
    QtGui.QMessageBox.No
)
```

I want to make bold,like:

```
"Are you sure you want to delete file?\n <b>%s</b>"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try that? Also if you are going to use HTML you should use `<br>` instead of `\n`. By default `QMessageBox` tries to determine whether you use HTML by using [`mightBeRichText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#mightBeRichText) this checks if there is something that looks like a tag **before the first newline**, hence changing `\n` to `<br>` should let `QMessageBox` auto-detect the HTML.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta thanks a lot. I get it.I have just started learning PySide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PySide's documentation you can use the [`setTextFormat`](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QMessageBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QMessageBox.setTextFormat) to specify the `Qt.RichText` format.

However this will only work when you create a custom `QMessageBox` *instance* and then set it up, it will not work when using the `QMessageBox.information` static-method.

By default `QMessageBox` uses the `Qt.AutoText` format which tries to detect whether the text is rich text by using the [`Qt.mightBeRichText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#mightBeRichText) function (I could only find Qt's documentation). The documentation of that function states:

> Returns true if the string text is likely to be rich text; otherwise
>   returns false.
>
> This function uses a fast and therefore simple heuristic. **It mainly
>   checks whether there is something that looks like a tag before the
>   first line break.** Although the result may be correct for common cases,
>   there is no guarantee.

Unfortunately in your message you have a line break `\n` *before* any tag, and hence the function fails to detect your message as rich text.

In any case once you interpret the text as rich text you have to use the HTML line break `<br>` so using the message:

```
"Are you sure you want to delete file?<br> <b>%s</b>"
```

will make the `QMessageBox` auto-detect the rich text and produce the result you want.